# Are women in hijab assumed not to be "asking for it" in sexual assault cases?

Tags: sharia, women, hijab, rape

In cases of sexual assault against women, the victim might be asked questions like *what was she wearing?* leading to the implication that she was somehow "asking for it" (i.e. provoking her attacker) if she was wearing a certain style of clothing, thereby giving the perpetrator a mitigating factor.  It's a form of [victim blaming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victim_blaming):

> A typical expression of victim blaming is the "asking for it" idiom, e.g. "she was asking for it" said of a victim of violence or sexual assault.

I'm wondering what would happen in a sexual assault case brought to a sharia court where the female victim was wearing hijab.

**Question**: Are women in hijab assumed not to be "asking for it" in sexual assault cases?

It's possible the sharia could interpret hijab as an unequivocal expression that she is not "asking for it".

Comment: Sharia court most likely won't take that into consideration. The perpetrator would be punished if he is found guilty even if the girl was naked. He is supposed to lower his gaze not assault her.

Comment: Is there some specific reason why you think that such excuses are admittable in Hadd and Qisas punishments in shariah? A Zani is punished even if they claim temptation, a drinker is punished even if they claim depression, a murderer or assaulter is punished even if they claim provocation.

Comment: @Uma: It's quite possible this is simply a misunderstanding on my part due to lack of familiarity with the processes.

Comment: You're mixing different questions here as far as I can tell, one is "is a woman who gets sexually assaulted while not observing hijab partially blamed for getting assaulted", and the other is "does her lack of hijab have legal relevance in a trial". Which one is the one you meant to ask?

Comment: Unlike western law, there is no concept of *ambiguity of consent*. The intercourse itself is inherently unlawful in Islam in the absence of a provable Nikah, and private consent does not constitute a valid Nikah. The Hadd will be carried out when proof of action is established and the perpetrator is only excused because of lunacy, minority or violent compulsion. So no, the victim will not be asked about her clothing, nor will it be admitted as an excuse or mitigation.

Comment: @Uma maybe you should consider answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

From a legal perspective, the act of assault is an offence in and of itself, regardless of what she was wearing. Islamic law ordains covering up - dressing modestly and lowering one's gaze - and the perpetrator is guilty of not lowering his gaze even if she were naked.

However, your question's opening suggests that you're also interested in perception beyond just the legal consequences. In that case, I would say that it varies greatly across societies and cultures. You just need to look around to find the most bizarre kinds of victim blaming in the news, from eye contact to speaking in a particular manner to smiling to whatnot.